# angular directive listen to prop change not acts

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I created a directive that renders a d3, it gets his data from props like this:

```
<my-directive words="fromControllerData"></my-directive>
```

now the "fromControllerData" can change by the parent and I want to rerender my directive.

How do I listen to the data change?

found many examples but none worked...

here is a link to the project: https://plnkr.co/edit/I6eyFMBrhoDpxfOsulrI?p=preview

you would see the directive on:

```
app.js // line 48
```

I tried scope.$watch and scope.$watchCollection ...

some code for explaining:

the conroller:

```
app.controller('AppController', ['$scope', '$rootScope', 'serverData', function($scope, $rootScope, serverData) {
$scope.data = {
    words: serverData
};

setTimeout(function() {
  console.log('changegd');
  $scope.data.words = [];  
}, 1000);

}]);
```

some directive code:

```
app.directive("gravityWordCloud", ['serverData', function(serverData) {
return {
    restrict: "EA",
    scope: {
        words: "="
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        // dontcare stuff

        //this happens only on first load......
        //but never again
        scope.$watchCollection('words', function() {
          console.log(scope.words);

        });

    }
}
}])
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
scope.$watch('scope.words', function() {
    console.log(scope.words);
}, true);
```

The $watch function only compares the reference of the object, which doesn't change. Adding the last 'true' parameter makes it a 'deep' watch. Function signature from the Angular documentation (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope):

```
$watch(watchExpression, listener, [objectEquality]);
```

Another approach would be to create a function that returns the words, and watch the function:

```
scope.$watch(function() {
    return someFunctionThatReturnsWords();
}, function() {
    console.log(scope.words);
});
```

Edit: You also watched 'words' instead of 'scope.words'

Comment: I just saw another error: you also have to watch 'scope.words' instead of 'words'.

Comment: tried that as well :/    take a look if you can make it work on the code, I really wasted 9 hours on that....

Answer (score 0):

I've added the following code to your Plunker, and this works:

```
var getWords = function() {
    return scope.words;
}

scope.$watch(getWords, function() {
    console.log(scope.words);              
}, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well whoever gets this error, it is the smallest thing but a huge time waste...

I noticed the "words" variable is not updated in the controller scope as well when it is on "timeout" but when I alter it manually later with another method while clicking something suddenly I see the change of the timeout as well.

Bottom line:
when I change the javascript:

```
setTimeout
```

to angular:

```
$timeout
```

suddenly all worked fine...

so it is probably something with scopes and stuff...